# How to pass a macro output to \FPeval?

Tags: fp

How to pass a macro output `\X{Tpeak}` to `\FPeval\Ypeak` as shown in the following code?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\endcsname{round(#3:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

\const{Vinit}{10}
\const{Theta}{75/180*pi}
\const{Gravity}{10}

\def\X#1{Vinit*cos(Theta)*#1}
\def\Y#1{Vinit*sin(Theta)*#1-Gravity*pow(2,#1)/2}

\const{Tpeak}{Vinit*sin(Theta)/Gravity}

\const{Ypeak}{\X{Tpeak}}

\const{Xpeak}{pow(2,Vinit)*sin(2*Theta)/(2*Gravity)}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](2\dimexpr\Xpeak\psxunit\relax,\Ypeak)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `\X{Tpeak}` needs to be expanded first, before passing to `\const`.

```
\edef\next{%
  \noexpand\const{Ypeak}{\X{Tpeak}}%
}\next
```

First `\X` is fully expanded, but not `\const` because of `\noexpand`. Then `\next` contains:

```
\const {Ypeak}{Vinit*cos(Theta)*Tpeak}
```

Macro `\next` is only temporarily used. Therefore a typical pattern is to put this
in a group:

```
\begingroup
\edef\next{\endgroup
  \noexpand\const{Ypeak}{\X{Tpeak}}%
}\next
```

Then a previously defined `\next` remains unchanged afterwards and `\const` is still
called outside the group.